# Console when ubuntu starts up

Tags: startup, console

When I start ubuntu up a purple screen pops up and then disapears again then a window comes up that says that I am running in low graphics mode. I click ok and then all I see is a black console. **How do I get into the normal ubuntu?**

Comment: Check this [here][1] for some guidelines


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

Comment: Provide some more info: has it worked before? Does the live cd work?

Comment: @OlupotDouglas - links are done simply with `[LINK NAME](http://www.URL...)` - e.g `Check this [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) for some guidelines` in markdown would make *'Check this [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) for some guidelines'*